# Proper way to handle ajax HTML block

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

So I was wondering what is the "spec" or "proper" way to handle HTML that is used via ajax.

For example, should I keep all the HTML in the actual page that is using it? Or should I just an ajax call to load it in?

Is there performance increase in keeping it loaded in the page since its one less load? Or does loading that extra data at page load off-set it.

Here is a screenshot illustrating what I mean.. You can see the {name} which is changed depending on what the user provide (limited characters of course).

Any help/opinion is appreciated! Thanks!

Partial source for those asking:

```
<!-- text field -->
    <div class="add-field-wrapper float-left">
        <input type="radio" value="text" name="input_type" id="rad-type-text" class="type-radio-btn">
        <label for="rad-type-text" class="radio-lbl" data-tooltip="Used for simple inputs such as: <b>Phone Number</b> or <b>Email Address</b>">
            <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=16&txt=70x70&w=70&h=70" class="field-type-icon" />
            <div class="field-type-text">Text Field</div>
        </label>
    </div>

    <!-- select -->
    <div class="add-field-wrapper float-left">
        <input type="radio" value="select" name="input_type" id="rad-type-select" class="type-radio-btn">
        <label for="rad-type-select" class="radio-lbl" data-tooltip="Use this option when you need to provide a list of choices for the user." >
            <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=16&txt=70x70&w=70&h=70" class="field-type-icon" />
            <div class="field-type-text">Select Menu</div>
        </label>
    </div>

    <!-- textarea -->
    <div class="add-field-wrapper float-left">
        <input type="radio" value="textarea" name="input_type" id="rad-type-textarea" class="type-radio-btn">
        <label for="rad-type-textarea" class="radio-lbl" data-tooltip="The textarea field will appear as a <b>WYSIWIG</b> (What you see is what you get) editor. This allows for some customization of the appearance of the input.">
            <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=16&txt=70x70&w=70&h=70" class="field-type-icon" />
            <div class="field-type-text">Text Area</div>
        </label>
    </div>
```

[image]

Edit:

```
    <!-- Datepicker HTML block - used in JS -->
<div id="datepicker_html" style="display: none;">
    <div id="{name}-block" class="datepicker-wrapper form-input-wrapper">
        <div class="template-drag-handle"><img src="images/design/up-down-icon.png" class="template-drag-handle-icon" alt="Drag" /></div>
        <div class="inputs-wrapper">
            <div class="form-row"><input type="text" name="{name}" class="input-datepicker" placeholder="{placeholder}" id="{name}"/></div>
        </div>
        <?php echo $default_template_chkbox_options_html; ?>
    </div>  
</div>
```

That's a "piece" of the html.. it gets loaded into a JS variable:

This is what processes it -- adds the name, changes the placeholder (these can be reused as many times as you want)

```
function addDatePickerField(){
    //Get the HTML
    var datepicker_html = $('#datepicker_html').html();

    datepicker_html = datepicker_html.replaceAll(/{name}/g, input_name_underscores);
    datepicker_html = datepicker_html.replaceAll('{placeholder}', input_name);

    $('#template-fields-wrapper').append(datepicker_html);

    wrapUpAddInput('datepicker');
}
```

I just didnt now it if would be better to do an ajax call, store the "external" html and call it in when I need it -- Like, that datepicker HTML block, would be store in separate file, then on a link, load into the DOM.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking here... are you asking if it's better to load html through ajax calls or leave it hard coded into the html file? Also, what is that {name} expression? is that from angular.js or something? or how did you manage to use that?

Comment: As with most things: it depends.  I usually pass *data only* back with AJAX requests and place the data where it belongs with javascript, but in some instances it makes sense to pass back full HTML.

Comment: **To all users who thing it's a good idea to embed a picture of your developer console**: It's MUCH more useful, and just as simple, to copy-pasted the actual markup - whether from a "View Source", or from your Console.

Comment: Basically, instead of hard coding the HTML in the javascript and just load it into a javascript variable.The {name} gets replaced with a user provided name, limited to letters and spaces. Just a way to keep track. This is just a small piece of a much bigger puzzle and was just curious if it would be better to just hard code the HTML or just use an AJAX call to load it in when I need it.

Comment: Why not put the HTML into the document?  Why store it in a js variable?

Comment: It is stored in the document, but then I load it into a JS variable to change the name.. I'll edit to elaborate further.

Comment: @cale_b Didn't mean to offend, note taken. Code pasted.

Answer (score 0):

I will try to address your question, even though it's a very broad one.

Generally, loading your content (e.g. HTML) dynamically via an ajax request does not always give you a performance boost, it really depends what you are doing and trying to achieve.

Should you always pre-load all of your HTML content with the initial request ? Or should you ajax load a portion of it after the page is already loaded on screen ? that is solely depends on your application and needs.

I will explain by an example:

Assuming I am developing a content site, which will be mainly content oriented (e.g articles) and will be served from traditional web browsers (desktop or mobile) then loading my articles for each page via ajax might not be a good idea, with very few rare exceptions.

On the other hand-

If I am developing a web application that needs to send and receive blocks of data in "real time", a project that contains a rich UI which has to have a rich and "enterprise"-like experience where stuff is being executed, updated and displayed on-the-fly smoothly without having to refresh and re-load my application page every time I am saving my work or executing an operation - I will certainly use ajax requests for handling some of that work.

Another aspect is the overall loading time of your page:

Some web-sites are loading some of their HTML via ajax after the page body is loaded - by doing this they are reducing the perceived loading-time of the page, by "perceived" I mean - to the user, it appears to load faster since the partial page is loading almost instantly, and then some blocks inside of the page are loading async via ajax.

Like i've said, this is a very broad question and there are many methods to learn and investigate to finally see what works best for your specific needs.

Good luck

Comment: Its definitely a dynamic application, lots of things happening on one page. Not static like a blog.

Comment: In this case I would strongly consider loading a partial version of the page and load the rest dynamically via ajax once the page is already in the browser.
it will put more load on your server (more requests per each screen, multiply this by the number of concurrent users) but it will give your end-user a much better experience.

If you are looking to save requests to\from the server you should also look into the various of caching methods available (both client and server side)

Comment: Yeah, That's what  think i am going to do. Thanks